# GitVersion counter reset to zero

Tags: gitversion

We would like to use GitVersion for your git repo and the following is our branching strategy.

Master - development branch which will build and deploy every pull request merged. 1.0.0-alpha.x
Release/v1.x.x - release branch which will be deployed end of sprint. 1.0.0-beta.x
Hotfix - branched from master and cherry pick to release branch.

Currently the version on master branch is working fine as 1.0.0-alpha.36 but when i created release branch (release/v1.0.0) it created a version 1.0.0-beta.0 instead 1.0.0-beta.36. What configuration i can set to achieve above.

GitVersion.yml

```
next-version: 1.0.2
mode: ContinuousDeployment
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: ''
branches:
  master:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: 'alpha'
  pull-request:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: 'pr'
    increment: None
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    tag-number-pattern: '[/-](?<number>\d+)[-/]'
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: (pull|pull\-requests|pr|[0-9]+)[/-]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false

  release:
    regex: release?[/]
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: 'beta'
    is-release-branch: true
ignore:
  sha: []
merge-message-formats: {}
```

Please advise ?